# Verify Nijenhuis tensor is a (1,2) tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I've been working the following problem:

> If $T_i^j$ is a type (1,1) tensor field show that $$ H_{ij}^k = T_i^r
>  \dfrac{\partial T_j^k}{\partial x^r} - T_j^r \dfrac{\partial
>  T_i^k}{\partial x^r} +  T_r^k \left( \dfrac{\partial T_i^r}{ \partial
>   x^j} - \dfrac{\partial T_j^r}{\partial x^i} \right) $$ is a type (1,2)
>    tensor.
>
> *$-$From Tensors, Differential Forms, and Variational Principles by Lovelock and Rund (p.99).*

and after introducing the transformation $x^i = x^i(\bar{x}^\alpha)$ and expanding, I'm able to show $$ \begin{align*} H_{ij}^k &= \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\alpha}{\partial x^i} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\beta}{\partial x^j} \dfrac{\partial x^k}{\partial \bar{x}^\gamma} \overline{H}_{\alpha \beta}^\gamma \\ &+ \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^i} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\nu}{\partial x^j} \dfrac{\partial x^k}{\partial \bar{x}^\lambda} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\rho}{\partial x^r} \dfrac{\partial^2 x^r}{\partial \bar{x}^\sigma \partial \bar{x}^\nu} \overline{T}_\rho^\lambda \overline{T}_\mu^\sigma - \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^j} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\nu}{\partial x^i} \dfrac{\partial x^k}{\partial \bar{x}^\lambda} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\rho}{\partial x^r} \dfrac{\partial^2 x^r}{\partial \bar{x}^\sigma \partial \bar{x}^\nu} \overline{T}_\rho^\lambda \overline{T}_\mu^\sigma \end{align*} $$ by noting that $$\begin{align*} T_a^b &= \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^a} \dfrac{\partial x^b}{\partial \bar{x}^\nu}\overline{T}_\mu^\nu \\ \dfrac{\partial T_a^b}{\partial x^c} &= 
\dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\lambda}{\partial x^c} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^a} \dfrac{\partial x^b}{\partial \bar{x}^\nu} \dfrac{\partial \overline{T}_\mu^\nu}{\partial \bar{x}^\lambda} + \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\lambda}{\partial x^c} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^a} \dfrac{\partial^2 x^b}{\partial \bar{x}^\nu \partial \bar{x}^\lambda} \overline{T}_\mu^\nu, \end{align*}$$

but I haven't been able to get the last two terms to cancel. Any help would be appreciated.

---

As Ted mentioned in the comments, my derivative of $T$ was missing a term: $$\dfrac{\partial T_a^b}{\partial x^c} = \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\lambda}{\partial x^c} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^a} \dfrac{\partial x^b}{\partial \bar{x}^\nu} \dfrac{\partial \overline{T}_\mu^\nu}{\partial \bar{x}^\lambda} + \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\lambda}{\partial x^c} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^a} \dfrac{\partial^2 x^b}{\partial \bar{x}^\nu \partial \bar{x}^\lambda} \overline{T}_\mu^\nu  + 
\dfrac{\partial x^b}{\partial \bar{x}^\nu} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^a \partial x^c} \overline{T}_\mu^\nu. $$ After correcting this term and using identity (3.19) from Lovelock and Rund, I am able to show that $$ H_{ij}^k = \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\alpha}{\partial x^i} \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\beta}{\partial x^j} \dfrac{\partial x^k}{\partial \bar{x}^\gamma} \overline{H}_{\alpha \beta}^\gamma $$ as desired.

Comment: I don't know if it helps for your approach, but there is a coordinate-free definition of the Nijenhuis tensor in terms of the Lie bracket of vector fields, which might be easier to work with: $H(X,Y)=[HX,HY]-H([HX,Y]+[X,HY]-H[X,Y])$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks for the suggestion. Some of your H's above should probably be J's (for the almost complex structure). I've shown the $f$-linearity of $H$ in a previous course (though it was a couple years ago) using the coordinate-free definition. Now I'm trying to get better at whipping around indices.

Comment: Aren't you missing a term in your computation of $\dfrac{\partial T^b_a}{\partial x^c}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin There should have been a $\dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\lambda}{\partial x^c} \dfrac{\partial  }{\partial \bar{x}^\lambda}\left( \dfrac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^a}  \right) \dfrac{\partial x^b}{ \partial \bar{x}^\nu} T_\mu^\nu $, but I changed the order of differentiation on the $\bar{x}^\mu$ term to get a Kronecker delta that vanishes under the subsequent differentiation by $\partial x^a$. Now I'm thinking this might not have been valid.

Comment: No, I'm talking about a factor of the type $\dfrac{\partial^2 \bar x^\mu}{\partial x^c\partial x^a}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Exactly, I'm getting that term now. I think the calculation will go now. Thank you.

Comment: @Mobius: Ah, yes, I meant to write $T$ (to match the notation in your question) on the right-hand side, of course.